# htaccess redirect if certain query pattern found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i would like to redirect from

```
www.site1.info?index.php?id=243&L=&tx_kesearch_pi1%5Bsword%5D=YOU
www.site1.info/search/search/?L=&tx_kesearch_pi1[sword]=YOU
```

TO

```
www.site2.org?index.php?id=243&L=&tx_kesearch_pi1%5Bsword%5D=YOU
www.site2.org/search/search/?L=&tx_kesearch_pi1[sword]=YOU
```

CAUTION

**i only want to redirect ONLY if ...**

```
www.site1.info?index.php?id=243
www.site1.info/search/search/
```

... and than redirect with the ongoing query (porting it to the site2.org

i tried unsuccessfully:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)site1\.info/index.php?id=243$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.site2.org/index.php?id=243%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please learn some basic terminology. That `www.site1.info/index.php?id=243` is not a host name should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match `REQUEST_URI` OR `QUERY_STRING` in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}`.

You can use this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)site1\.info$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=243(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.site2.org/index.php?id=243%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)site1\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/search/?$ http://www.site2.org/index.php?id=243%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: it's not working. Also, the site2 is in cpanel set as the doc-root (typo3) of site1. So i switched rewrite condition ^index\.php$ to an absolute url http://www.site2.org/index\.php$

Comment: No you CANNOT do that that will be wrong rule. Above code needs to be placed in DocumentRoot of `site1.info`

Comment: Hi its not easily (server level) possible to do that. i would have to somehow clearly define the Absolute url

Comment: See may answer for an example on how to match HOST and URI. For more specific help you can edit your question and clarify your requirement so that I can customize my answer.